# Integrated sound card not working Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

After updating from 18.04 to 20.04 the integrated sound card is not working anymore. 
The only recognized audio devices are the GPU and a pair of headsets with integrated audio on USB.

All the jack 3.5 ports are not working. This problem is 100% from Ubuntu because I've made a test on Windows 10 and everything is working fine.

The audio chipset is Realtek S1220A.

Did somebody encountered this problem and knows how it can be solved? Based on the current global situation with the pandemic, I need to use my jack 3.5 microphone and stereo system.

[Terminal informations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MZYj.png)

What I have tried:
`pulseaudio -v` shows

```
E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.
```

- Unstall & Install `alsa-base pulseaudio linux-sound-base alsa-utils`
- `pulse restore`
- `inxi -A | grep driver` shows
  `Audio:     Device-1: Intel 200 Series PCH HD Audio driver: N/A`

Comment: I suspect you have a similar issue and need to reinstall the driver like in my case https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/630608/452327

Comment: Hmm, it sounds promising, but what fixed my system was, I'm not crazy, unplug the power cord and let the computer rest for 2 days. I guess my computer was on his period. I'll keep that solution in mind!